# Compilation fails with valid code when "Fastest -O" optimizations are set

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

The following code is a valid Swift code and does compile correctly when optimizations are disabled.

```
protocol Foo {
    var bar: String { get set }
}

class BaseFoo: Foo {
    var bar: String = "hello"
}

class ChildFoo: BaseFoo {
    private var _bar: String = "world"

    override var bar: String {
        get {
            return _bar
        }
        set {
            _bar = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Once I enable Swift optimizations (Fastest -O), I only get a very vague error message from xcode:

> Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

So I tried to run the command Xcode said was failing and I was able to find more interesting error:

> PHINode should have one entry for each predecessor of its parent basic block!
>   %11 = phi i64 [ %43, %33 ], [ 0, %29 ], !dbg !747
>   LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that there is a bug in the compiler. Somehow it has problem with overriding read-write properties defined in protocols. I could not find a solution, only these following workarounds:

1. If you make the property read-only in the protocol (by changing `{ get set }` to `{ get }`), the error will disappear. Unfortunately you will not be able to rewrite the variable if you do not have access to the implementation type (and you should not do that, because otherwise you lose the goodness protocols bring you)
2. Do not override the property in the child class (in our case `ChildFoo`). If you do not override it, you will not hit this error. On the other hand, you probably would not overriding it if you did not need to do that, so this will not help you much.
3. Last but not least the workaround that gives you overriding support and read-write access (well, sort of). Change the protocol to not have a variable, but getter and setter methods. That way you can set the value from the outside and you can also override the behavior of either get or set.

I ended up using the third workaround, because I need both read-write and override support. So at the end my code would look like this:

```
protocol Foo {
    func getBar() -> String

    func setBar(bar: String)
}

class BaseFoo: Foo {
    private var bar: String = "hello"

    func getBar() -> String {
        return bar
    }

    func setBar(bar: String) {
        self.bar = bar
    }
}

class ChildFoo: BaseFoo {
    private var _bar: String = "world"

    override func getBar() -> String {
        return _bar
    }

    override func setBar(bar: String) {
        _bar = bar
    }
}
```

I filled a radar report http://www.openradar.appspot.com/21603216 so hopefully Apple will fix it. I have **not** tried this in the new Xcode **nor** in Swift 2.0.

Hopefully this will help anyone who will have the same problem.